# Logback default pattern layout

Tags: logback, spring-logback

Logback has a [DefaultNestedComponentRules class](https://javadoc.io/doc/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.12/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/DefaultNestedComponentRules.html)  that sets the [default layout](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/onJoran.html#defaultClassMapping) to use if none is specified in the configuration of an appender/encoder.

How can I override this? I have extended PatternLayout and want this to be the default.

Can I do this via my *logback.xml* file? Or does it have to be done programatically?

I'm using Spring Boot, in case that's relevant.